# programming sorting numbers out of order

Tags: java

I'm doing a bubble sort program in java for school and it isn't sorting anything. I don't know why
this is the code for the bubble sort

```
double temp;    
    int i=bubbleSortArray.length-1;
    int i2 =0;
    
    while (i>0)         //loop until array is sorted
    {
        while (i2<i)    //once the loop has been completed and the numbers that are largest are in the correct position this ensures the code does not go through these numbers again.
        {
            if(bubbleSortArray[i2]>bubbleSortArray[i2+1])   //check if number is smaller than other number
            {
                temp=bubbleSortArray[i2];   //store number for swap

                bubbleSortArray[i2]=bubbleSortArray[i2+1];

                bubbleSortArray[i2+1]=temp; //swap both numbers
            }
            i2++;
        }
        i--;
    }
```

output:
sorted: 284.08, 279.51, 226.95, 493.75, 304.59, 485.65, 384.07, 256.38, 194.49, 294.43, 490.54, 431.75, 312.42, 323.87, 204.28, 296.4, 420.88, 303.49, 499.29,

Comment: Maybe you need to reset `i2` to zero.

Comment: Directly before `while (i2<i)` set `i2 = 0`, otherwise the inner loop is only entered during the first iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static < T extends Comparable<T> >
        void bubbleSort( T[] data )
{   
    for( int i = ( data.length - 1 ) ; i >= 0 ; --i )
    {   
        for( int j = 0 ; j < i ; ++j )
        {   
            if( data[j].compareTo(data[j+1] ) > 0 )
            {
                swap( data, j, ( j + 1 ) ) ;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

This is a bubbleSort on a generic array. If you want it just double make the method signature

```
public static void bubbleSort( Double[] data)
```

and it has to be big Double because you can't run compareTo on double

You can write the swap method inline essentially, but here's my method of it

```
private static <T> 
        void swap( T[] data, int pos1, int pos2 )
{
    T temp = data[ pos1 ] ;
    data[ pos1 ] = data[ pos2 ] ;
    data[ pos2 ] = temp ;
}
```

You can still redo this a bit without using .compareTo() and essentially inline that with the < > comparison if tree

Comment: You don't need to implement swap yourself. You can use `Collections.swap(Arrays.asList(data), pos1, pos2)`